# MFC: Why do I need to use CListCtrl::SetExtendedStyle() instead of CListCtrl::ModifyStyleEx()?

Tags: mfc, clistctrl

Question is why doesn't `CListCtrl::ModifyStyleEx()` work but `CListCtrl::SetExtenedStyle()` does?  See below:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
  CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

  //m_MyList.ModifyStyleEx(0, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);   <<- Doesn't Work!
  m_MyList.SetExtendedStyle(m_MyList.GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT); // <<- Works!
}
```

Comment: If you spy the code ModifyStyle eventually invokes SetWindowLong with GWL_EXSTYLE. A quick search in MSDN states that LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT must be turned on with  LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE message which SetExtendedStyle delivers. So just follow MSDN.

Comment: I see, ModifyStyleEx changes windows styles, not a listview control style.

Comment: Follow this Question https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/57590ad2-1924-4689-a908-52fee0ed5f28/setextendedstyle-and-modifystyleex?forum=vcmfcatl for the rightful explanation of the ModifyStyleEx() vs SetExtendedStyle()